# I’m looking for some new ideas to make a full talking character

Tags: animation, rigging, fcurves

let’s say that I want to create something like this :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qE72InFJrM

[image: full talking character]

this can be done easily with **crazy talk animator**,but we like to use **blender**,right ? let’s say also that I know how to **blink the eyes** and how to **move the mouth in syncro with the voice**. what I don’t know how to do is how to make swing the head,**the shoulder and the torso** a little according with the movements of the lips and of the eyes. I think how to do that for some time and right now I haven’t found any tutorial that teaches me a little how to do that. This tutorial for example teaches how to synch the lips and it makes the character speaks nicely,BUT when it does it,his head and his shoulders don't move,so it's not very realistic.

[Lipsinc for the Lazy in Blender 2: Realism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8u7QnokpGk&t=1070s)

Maybe I can apply the same tecnique that I use to sync the lips with the voice,but this time,instead of using the lips,I can use the head and the shoulders ? Do you have some good ideas to achieve the goal ?

Comment: I don't think there's any rules or tools to do that, you just try some moves with the shoulder and head and see if it makes your character more realistic

Comment: I know,but I would like to automate a little the procedure

Comment: Thinking better to what I want to do,I would like to make some corrections to what I said before. Infact I think that instead of talking about to move the shoulders,its better to talk about to move the diaphragm. Infact I think that it has no big sense to create a set of new shapekeys to simulate the moving of the shoulders. Bastioni lab has two shapekeys that can be used for this : Expressions_abdomExpansion_max and min ; Expressions_chestExpansion_max and min that can be repeated,because the breath is cyclic.

Comment: This tutorial can be used to create a cyclic breathing :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f63qVMG2VA0

If we want to create a realistic talking head there are some other little movements to simulate. For example a random deglutition. Bastioni has the shapekey "Expressions_deglutition_max and min" and for moving the head I can't make any new shapekey,because the head movement does not imply a movement of the mesh. For this a BVH file can be used.